# Show the expected number of packets to buy to collect a whole set of minifigures

Tags: probability, expectation

Minifigures are sold in packets, where each packet contains one minifigure, and from the outside of the packet it is impossible to tell which minifigure is inside. There are $n$ minigures to collect.

Assuming that each packet that is bought is equally likely to contain any one of the
figures, show that the expected number of packets that needs to be bought to collect
the whole set is approximately $n \log n$.

Comment: Please see the Wikipedia article on the [Coupon Collector's Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) The problem has also been repeatedly solved on MSE.

Comment: This smells like a test question, given that two people have asked this "time-appropriate" question within 1 hour of each other.

Answer (score 0):

First create a series representing the chance of getting a mini-figure, assuming there are 4:

$$(4/4) + (3/4) + (2/4) + (1/4)$$

The first one has a 100% of not being already taken. After that there are 3 remaining. Now 2, before finally trying to get that last Lego. The average amount of figures bought before getting the correct figure is the series' reciprocal, aka. 1/4 says I average 4 attempts before getting the figure. 3/4 says I average 4/3 attempts. The true series is for total attempts is:

$$(4/4) + (4/3) + (4/2) + (4/1)$$

In series notation I get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^4 \frac 4n$$

or, more generally, for $x$ number of figures:

$$\sum_{n=1}^x \frac xn = x\sum_{n=1}^x \frac 1n$$

Which equals $xH_x$, $H_n$ being the $n$th harmonic number (Harmonic numbers defined as $\sum_{n=1}^x \frac 1n$). The harmonic numbers approach $ln(x)$, proofs found elsewhere, so the total estimated numbers of attempts is $xln(x)$, substituting $H_x$ with $ln(x)$.

Note: Using the $ln(x)$ is semi-accurate, using the harmonic series is purely accurate. Even as $n$ approaches infinity, the $ln(x)$ is $0.5772156649...$ away from the harmonic series (That number is the Euler–Mascheroni constant).